# Undo "hide for now" in Chrome history

Tags: google-chrome

1. [chrome://history/](http://chrome://history/)
2. Click on the drop-down next to a different device
3. Select "Hide for now" and the device and its history disappear from the list

That's well and good but how do I get it back? Refreshing or exiting and reloading the tab doesn't restore the device's listing.

Comment: I accidentally did this too. Why the F would anyone want this feature is beyond me especially when it's not obvious how to undo it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem recently and this solution from a Google Groups solved it for me.

So you have to view new tabs and then refresh the history page: chrome://history/ and then click on the "Tabs from other devices" button to get these back.

> I found that a device's tabs were again visible once I had again
>   accessed the tabs in the device's browser, then refreshed the history
>   and clicked "Tabs from other devices" yet again.
>
> In short, it appears that "Hide for now" removes your device's most
>   recent viewing session. While I haven't yet found a way to restore the
>   viewing session, you can again see the device's recent tabs after
>   you've viewed new tabs (or reloaded the same tabs) on the device.

Comment: phew, that worked

Answer (score 1):

They will come up when you open a new tab and use it in the hidden client.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so. For example, what is the "hidden client"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, The solution is ...

- Uninstall google chrome from the device that you currently hide (and want it to undo) for example iPhone google chrome app
- Re-install google chrome app again (on the device you want to make it appear in device tab in browser history)
- Then, The iPhone device will reappear again in the device history section in google chrome app in Macbook